# How to render multiple selected values in a Word template

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, office365-apps, word-template

I'm trying to render multiple values selected from checkbox on a form made by Powerapps where its data source is a Sharepoint list, the type of column I'm using for this field is of choice configured to allow me to select multiple values.

In my Powerapps form I am changing the combobox to checkbox as follows:

[image]

For the OnCheck and OnUncheck property of each Checkbox I make use of a Collection, this collection is called "ViadeExposicion" with the respective validations as follows:

```
ClearCollect(

    ViadeExposicion;

    If(

        Checkbox3.Value;

        "Respiratoria"

    );

    If(

        Checkbox4.Value;

        "Dérmica"

    );

    If(

        Checkbox5.Value;

        "Digestiva"

    );

    If(

        Checkbox6.Value;

        "Ocular"

    );

    If(

        Checkbox7.Value;

        "Otra"

    )

);;

ClearCollect(

    ViadeExposicion;

    Filter(

        ViadeExposicion;

        !IsBlank(Value)

    )

)
```

In my DataCard I have hidden the ComboBox with the values, as you can see I have the 5 checkbox that I use in my form.

[image]

In my Word template represent the options that I have in the checkboxes with plain text content control because the word online connector does not currently support the checkbox currently according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/wordonlinebusiness/#createfileitem%20).

[image]

As a help I came across someone who has a similar problem only who uses it with Yes/No column types [Here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Populate-Word-with-Checkbox/td-p/403194) it's an idea that works wonders when you use Yes/No columns, but it's not much help when you have to select multiple values (or so I think so far).

I would like someone to give me some guidance on how I can represent the multiple values selected in checkbox, I would quite appreciate it.